# java-Cast String Arraylist to double ArrayList

Tags: java, string, casting, double

I have a **String arraylist** and i am going to convert it to a **double arraylist**. Is there any way except using loops like *for,While* to convert it?

```
ArrayList<String>  S=new ArrayList<String>();

S=FillTheList();

ArrayList<Double>  D=new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Comment: If you use Guava, yes. The JDK per se has no such mechanism, at least not up to version 7. Version 8 will have support for it, though.

Comment: Side note: what's the point of assigning an empty ArrayList to `S` (which should be named `s`), if you reassign a new list (returned by `FillTheList()`, which should be named `fillTheList()`) to `S` immediately after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the JDK proper, up to version 7, no. JDK 8 will have functional programming support, though (see comment by @JBNizet below for the syntax).

You can use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to achieve this however:

```
final Function<String, Double> fn = new Function<String, Double>()
{
    @Override
    public Double apply(final String input)
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
};

// with S the original ArrayList<String>

final List<Double> D = Lists.transform(S, fn);
```

Note that while there is no loop in this code, internally the code will use loops anyway.

More to the point of your original question however, you cannot cast a `String` to a `Double`, since these are two different classes. You have to go through a parsing method like shown above.

Comment: Just for the record, in Java 8, you can do `List<Double> d = s.stream().map(Double::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want your `ArrayList` to contain `Double`s when you're done, no, there's no alternative, you're going to have to loop through, converting each `String` to a `Double` and adding the `Double` to the new `ArrayList`.

Note that at runtime, Java doesn't actually know the type that a `List` contains - it doesn't know that it's an `ArrayList<Double>`, it just knows that it's an `ArrayList`.  There's therefore no way for the JVM to know what operation needs to happen to convert the contents of your `ArrayList<String>` (which it also sees as `ArrayList`) and add them to your `ArrayList<Double>`.